# using an automatic range to split cells

Tags: split, range, cell

so I've been trying to figure this out for a while now and I've found several topics on the same question. I can't get it to work though.

This is my code:

```
    Sub FindLast()
    Dim lCol As Long
    Dim lRox As Long
    Dim Copyrange As String


    lCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Column - 1 + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    lRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
End Sub


Sub NameSplit()

Dim txt As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim FullName As Variant
Dim x As String, cell As Range
Dim charray(181, 3) As Integer

For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1).Address(), Cells(lRow, lCol).Address()).Select
     txt = cell.Value
     FullName = Split(txt, "-")

     For i = 0 To UBound(FullName)
         cell.Offset(0, i + 1).Value = FullName(i)
         charray(j, i) = FullName(i)
     Next i

Next cell
End Sub
```

In the first sub I look for the last cell that contains information and I get a correct output for lCol and lRow.

In the second sub I'm trying to use these two values to split a range of cells. 
I tried different syntaxes for the range but i keep getting the error:

"application defined or object defined error"

I can't debug but I'm 90% sure the problem is in the following line:

```
 For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1).Address(), Cells(lRow, lCol).Address()).Select
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, speaking of the error, this is due to the fact that the value of lRow and lCol are not visible to sub namesplit. Define lRow and lcol as a global variable so that the values are visible and can be accessed by all of the modules.

Secondly, It would be good to know the details of what you are trying to perform in the namesplit sub which would atleast help me to guide you further.

Thanks..

Comment: "ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(lCol, lRow).Value"

Can you please check your second code again - the Test sub ? It has to be something like this .cells(IRow, ICol).value ?

You are passing the value of column in the place of rows and vice versa. Please rectify it and let us know if you are still getting some error.